# HTTP/HTTPS timeouts in/out because of DHCP?

Tags: http, https, dhcp, ovh

I'm trying to debug a new server I ordered at OVH.com and they insist everything is working properly even though it times out when doing a curl request towards for an example github.com (times out 9 in around 10 tries)

```
curl -L -v https://github.com
```

I get

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://github.com/
*   Trying 140.82.118.4...
* connect to 140.82.118.4 port 443 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Even when I set up NGINX sever, site timeouts almost every second request

So I thought perhaps DHCP server can be an issue so I checked it and I see this from (var/lib/dhcp..)

```
lease {
  interface "ens4";
  fixed-address 10.0.X.XX;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 10.0.X.X;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 10.0.X.X;
  option domain-name-servers 10.0.X.X;
  renew 6 2020/03/28 02:16:19;
  rebind 6 2020/03/28 13:47:57;
  expire 6 2020/03/28 16:47:57;
}
lease {
  interface "ens4";
  fixed-address 10.0.X.XX;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 10.0.X.X;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 10.0.X.X;
  option domain-name-servers 10.0.X.X;
  renew 5 2020/03/27 16:51:54;
  rebind 5 2020/03/27 16:51:54;
  expire 5 2020/03/27 16:51:54;
}
```

I tried getting a new one by doing this command but nothing changes, still the same as above

```
sudo dhclient -r
```

Am I looking at the DHCP wrong or does it look normal? For the record my public IP on this dedicated starts with 5 not 1 and it is run on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

What is the offer you have at OVH ? They usually don't give private IP to dedicated server or virtual private server, so that's quite odd.

You may want to collect some trace to check what is going wrong with tools like :

- `tcptraceroute` to check if the path to a domain on port 80 or 443
  looks strange
- `ping` to be able to see if there packet loss
- `tcpdump` to capture raw network packet while a timeout is occuring to see what's going on

That's a good start and may also help you go back to OVH Support and prove them there's something wrong.